# WebHttpBinding not reaching the client

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, webhttpbinding

I created a web service for which I am trying to provide 3 endpoints with different bindings.
1. basicHttpBinding,
2. wsHttpBinding,
3. webHttpBinding

When I make the service reference, I get only the endpoints with the basicHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding bindings created. I don't get webHttpBinding. What could possibly wrong.

Here's the structure of the serviceModel node in web.config.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
</diagnostics>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="VersionTolerance.Service1Behavior" name="BookShop.BookShopService">
    <endpoint address="sadha" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BookShop.IBookShopService" />
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="BookShop.IBookShopService" >
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
      contract="BookShop.IBookShopService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:49654/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="VersionTolerance.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>          
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing wrong - that's just the way it works!

`basicHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding` are SOAP bindings that expose metadata about their service - your Visual Studio `Add Service Reference` can interrogate their endpoints, find out what they're called, what methods they offer, what data types they expect as parameters and what they return.

`webHttpBinding` is REST - and REST by default doesn't have a concept of metadata - you won't get a service description, list of methods etc. - REST is all about **resources** - not methods.

So therefore, when you do a  `Add Service Reference`, you get proxy clients for the SOAP endpoints - but **not** for the REST / `webHttpBinding` endpoint. Works as designed.

The WCF Data Services - built on top of REST - offer a similar experience to the SOAP bindings, in that you can do an `Add Service Reference` and get a nice client side proxy and all - and this is done since the OData protocol defines a metadata exchange on top of REST. So if you can turn your REST service into a WCF Data Service, you'd be fine again.

Otherwise, with REST, you just have to "know" (from a documentation page or something) what the resource URI's for your REST service are, and what the HTTP verbs do in your REST context.

Comment: Thank you @marc_s, I would like to agree with your answer. But I would like to experience the webHttpBinding by creating a client to it.

In a layman term, what should I do to create a proxy to this service and start using it, in the Visual Studio?

Comment: @SaravananArumugam: as I tried to explain: with the "normal" webHttpBinding, you **cannot** get a client-side proxy - there is just no such thing. If you want a client-side proxy for a REST-based service, you need to create a **WCF Data Service** (see here: http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CSLA4Version41Release.aspx)